# What do __cdecl and (void) mean?

Tags: c++, void, cdecl

I'm currently programming a tcp/ip server using WSA. After some troubleshooting a friend of mine said that i should use `bool __cdecl winsock_server ( void )` instead of `bool winsock_server()`.

But he didn't explain to me what `__cdecl` and `(void)`
are doing. I already know that `__cdecl` changes the way how arguments are put on the stack on assembler level, but what does `(void)` mean?

I should point out that I'm new to C++. I only programmed in C# and VB.NET before.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They do nothing useful.  `__cdecl` is already the default calling convention for free functions, in C++ member functions are `__thiscall` and cannot be `__cdecl`.   Do not confuse it with `extern "C"` like the upvoted answer did.  `(void)` is only useful in C to emphasize that the function has zero arguments.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`__cdecl`
You got it right. It enforces function calling convention to c-style and thus the way function is called (How arguments are passed, who cleans stack). BTW this is already default calling convention.

`(void)` v/s `()`
In `C++` they are equivalent(no arguments).
In `C` however former means no arguments and latter means any number of arguments. So it can cause problems when you reuse the header file for `C`.

Comment: do i get any advantages when using __cdecl ?

Comment: @Th3Bamb00zl3r Yes, you get compatibility with 'C'. About the performance, there may be arguments on either side. (cdecl stands for c declaration)

Comment: cdecl ain't extern C, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/cdecl?view=vs-2019

Comment: @JVApen `__cdecl` is C calling convention. Both C and C++ symbols(functions and variable names) may use it. `extern C` is a C++ thing that suggests C++ compiler not to do name-mangling in C++ way. (C way is just an underscore before function name which is enough as function overloading is not supported). C++ declaration may use both or one or none according to the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

(void) means it has no arguments. It's more of a code style thing. you could use only () but writing (void) explicitly shows that the function have no arguments.

Comment: `()` also shows that the function has no arguments in C++.

Comment: yeah but writing (void) makes it more explicit. it's a code style thing. the compiler won' t care.

Comment: It's only "more explicit" if you're coming from C. In all other languages an empty parameter list means an empty parameter list. I don't think it's idiomatic C++.

Comment: @Niek: Yes it will

Comment: @melpomene It's because I read your comment as "in C" rather than "in C++" somehow 

Comment: It is NOT only a coding style thing! Writing function(void) means a function with no parameters (parameter type list is void), whereas function() *could* mean a function with multiple parameters; the amount is determined by the initializer list, not the parameter type list. I learned about this here: https://jameshfisher.com/2016/11/27/c-k-and-r/